# Amazon web services iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, linker-errors

I'm trying to set up an Xcode application with Amazon web service. When I put the frameworks from the downloaded SDK into the project, I get multiple Apple Mach-O Linker Errors. Am I possibly doing something wrong while adding them to the project that gives me these errors? Or do I need to be doing something with them in my code to prevent these errors?

Comment: No, still haven't found a solution

Comment: Here is the link, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/139#issuecomment-71288646 , May help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a iOS app skeleton with [Mobile Hub.](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/)

[AWS Mobile Hub](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/) guides you through feature selection and configuration, automatically provisions the AWS services required, and generates working code that helps you integrate the Mobile SDK with your app in minutes.